# mouse bug? ubuntu 12.04 acts as if i clicked the mouse when I didn't just after move

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I have a strange problem. I can not tell whether it is option someone might want but I don't  or broken hardware etc.

Every time I move the mouse and then wait a second any program will act as if the mouse was clicked, eg. move over a button but don't click, then wait a second and the program will act as if the button was clicked. It is extremely frustrating often causing focus to shift unexpectedly or firing off buttons I was just moving the mouse over.

I have swapped to several different mice and they all act the same.

Does anybody have any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an accessibility that enables this function I guess to make it easier on people who find it difficult to press the mouse buttons. Check your accessibility settings and make sure nothing is enabled that should not be.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how the option of "Hover Click" got set but that was the problem.